# how to display highcharts data and Xaxis in angular from @input()

Tags: angular, highcharts

I am using Highcharts for angular, and I want to assign series data and xAxis categories received from parent with input in angular 13, problem is that it is not showing in chart but when i log the data and xaxis it shows in the console , also tried to define chartOptions inside ngOnInit but still got nothing, here is my code:

HTML:

```
<highcharts-chart
    [Highcharts]="Highcharts"
    [options]="chartOptions"
    [(update)]="updateFlag"
    style="width: 100%; height: 360px; display: block"
  ></highcharts-chart>
```

TS:

```
ngOnInit(): void {
    this.chartOptions.xAxis.categories = this.chartCategories;
    this.chartOptions.series[0].data = this.chartData
    console.log(this.chartOptions.xAxis.categories,
                this.chartOptions.series[0].data);
     this.updateFlag = true;

  }

   

 @Input()
  public set options(options: {
    title: string;
    color: string;
    symbol: string;
    categories: string[];
    data: number[];
  }) {
    this.chartCategories = options.categories;
    this.chartData = options.data;
    this.chartColor = options.color;
    this.chartTitle = options.title;
    this.symbol = options.symbol;
    this.updateFlag = true;
    // this.chartOptions.xAxis.categories = options.categories;
    // this.chartOptions.series[0].color = options.color;
    // this.chartOptions.series[0].name = options.symbol;
    // this.chartOptions.series[0].data = options.data;
  }

Highcharts: typeof Highcharts = Highcharts;
  updateFlag = false;

  chartOptions: any = {
    chart: {
      type: 'bar',
    },
    title: {
      enabled: false,
      visible: false,
      text: '',
    },
    xAxis: {
      categories: [],
      title: {
        text: null,
      },
    },
    yAxis: {
      gridLineWidth: 0,
      minorGridLineWidth: 0,
      visible: true,
    },
    tooltip: {
      enabled: false,
    },
    plotOptions: {
      bar: {
        dataLabels: {
          enabled: false,
        },
      },
    },
    credits: {
      enabled: false,
    },
   
    series: [
      {
        color: 'red',
        name: 'some text',
        data: [],
      },
    ],
  };
```

Comment: Hi Beso, I'm not sure why you want to use @Input in main component, to get data and put it in chart options, using services will be more appropriate approach. Look at this [example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/highcharts-angular-data-from-a-service?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts).

Comment: Hi @SebastianHajdus , i want to display 9 different chart with 9 different options and i thought that it would be better if i had 1 chart component and pass the 9 different options like this: `<app-bar-chart [options]="passedOptionsForBarChart[0]"></app-bar-chart>``<app-bar-chart [options]="passedOptionsForBarChart[1]"></app-bar-chart>`

Comment: Do you want to show all charts on one page?

Comment: In this [example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/highcharts-angular-edit-data-gacgkq-dccjbp) you can see how I get data from parent component and using `@Input` inside child components, I hope it will be useful.